# I observed a Java process running at root level through top command on my application server, will it lead to performance problems?

Tags: linux, performance, performance-testing

We were running a load test and simultaneously executed top command and observed that Java process (running at root level) was consuming 204℅ cpu, even though we ran just 10℅ of expected load on server.

Also one of my colleagues said that a Java process should not be running at root level as this leads to performance issues.

I tried searching the internet but could not find anything which says that Java process should not run at root level.

Note for experts :- please excuse me for my lack of knowledge, please do not download or block the question.

Screen shot of top command:

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's incorrect -- running a process as root will not affect performance, but will likely affect security.

The reason why everyone says not to run your processes as root unless ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY is because the root user has privileges over the entire disk, and many other things: external devices, hardware, processes, etc.

Running code that interacts with the world as root means that if anyone can find a vulnerability in your code / project / process / whatever, the amount of damage / harm that can be done is likely WAY MORE than what could be possible by a non-root user.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below command to find all the processes in Tree Structure.

```
ps -e -o pid,args --forest
```

From the output, you will be able to figure out those java processes or other processes running at Root level are children of whom. For ex. sometimes while testing some scripts, we ourselves trigger those scripts with sudo which might in turn starts the java instance.